# Jquery Check all checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does my check all button work once and doesn't work at 3rd click. 
the check all button only works at firts click. I check the dom and its updating but the view does. What is the cause of the problem?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5KrCp/)**

```
jQuery('.sp_country').click(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox"),
        checked = checkbox.is(":checked");
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checked);

});

jQuery('.sp_country input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var checked = (e.currentTarget.checked) ? false : true;
    e.currentTarget.checked = (checked) ? false : checked.toString();
});

jQuery('#bt_checkbox').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (jQuery(this).val() === 'Uncheck All') {
        jQuery('#country input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        jQuery(this).val('Check All');
    } else {
        jQuery('#country input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
        jQuery(this).val('Uncheck All');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5KrCp/1/)</kbd>

Change

```
jQuery('#country input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

to

```
jQuery('#country input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

---

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)